# cannot find OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE or OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER

Tags: ruby, ssl, rvm, jruby, net-http

I have jruby 1.9 installed on a system and the OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE works fine on it.

I am trying to use the same code on a mac using rvm - ruby1.9.3 , ruby 1.8.7 and seems like its not working any more

I get the error :

```
undefined method `use_ssl=' for #<Net::HTTP
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Don't you need a `Net::HTTPS` object?

Comment: When I try that I get uninitialized constant Net::HTTPS